# How to find contours in dotted text captcha image

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am newbie to OpenCV. I'm trying to find the contours of the captcha image. It does not work only when my captcha image contains the dotted text.

I have done following code for that:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa

im = cv.imread('dataset/1.jpg')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

imgray = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)[1]

dst = cv.Canny(imgray,0,150)
blured = cv.blur(dst,(5,5),0)
img_thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(blured,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
threshed = cv.morphologyEx(img_thresh,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dst, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))
# cv.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv.imshow("img_thresh",img_thresh)
cv.imshow("dst",dst)
cv.imshow("threshed",threshed)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can anyone help in this? Is there any way to find contours in this image?

[image: here is my captcha image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code and output

```py
'''
contours
'''
import numpy as np
import cv2

#read image as gray
pic = r'C:\Users\balaji\Desktop\captcha.jpg'
img_color = cv2.imread(pic)
cv2.imshow('CAPTCHA preview',img_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_color,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Apply thresholding to the image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('Thresholded image', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Dilated image - to connect the dots
krn = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
img_dilated = cv2.dilate(cv2.bitwise_not(thresh), kernel=krn, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('Dilated image', img_dilated)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Finding and draw Contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
black_canvas = np.zeros_like(img_color)
cv2.drawContours(black_canvas, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imshow('Contoured image', black_canvas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: contour output stages]

Comment: thank you for giving the answer, it's working perfectly

Comment: The trick is the dilating to connect the dots.